# Lifehack to prevent freezer burn and ice on food (no ice in freezer itself)

Tags: food, kitchen, food-safety

I find that almost anything in my freezer gets ice in it, and often has freezer burn after about a month.  The freezer itself is free of ice.

This includes microwave dinners that come pre-sealed from the factory.  They will develop a significant amount ice inside in about a month.

Is there some way to prevent this, perhaps something I could put in the freezer?

Answer (score 1):

Freezer burn is caused by [sublimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezer_burn). If it happens, it suggests that the food packaging isn't airtight.

and:

> It is possible to slow freezer burn by filling plastic containers with water and leaving them open (leaving room for expansion) in the freezer to help maintain humidity.